# How can I add multiple table entries with a single json command in python?

Tags: python, mysql, json

I want to get multiple entries into a table using a single JSON input but I don't know how to go from here. I was to make it to where once the user states

```
[
 {
  "VIN": "kjasdfh",
  "Make": "Toyota",
  "model": "Corolla",
  "Year": 1998
 },
 {
  "VIN": "wqeiryu",
  "Make": "Honda",
  "model": "Civic",
  "Year": 1997
 }
]
```

I wasn't to make it where the first one has its own entries and the second one has another entry.

```
 @app.route('/api/addcar', methods = ['POST']) # This is a post method because the user needs to be able to add info
 def adding_stuff():
     request_data = request.get_json() # Gets the info from the table and converts to JSON format
     new_vin = request_data['VIN']
     new_make = request_data['Make']
     new_year = request_data['Year']
     new_color = request_data['Color']
     sql = "INSERT INTO carsTEST (VIN, Make, Year, Color, username) VALUES ('%s', '%s', %s, '%s')" % (new_vin, new_make, new_year, new_color) # This sql statement will then be uploaded to the databse to add a new record
     conn = create_connection()
     execute_query(conn, sql) # This will execute the query
     return 'Post worked'
```

Comment: not really sure what you need help on. you should definitely take out the `'%s'` bits and replace with `?`.  maybe this will help: https://pythonbasics.org/flask-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to turn your json array into a model array (with serializer or something your framework offers) .
Or try to build your raw sql with something like this:

```
json_data = [
 {
  "VIN": "kjasdfh",
  "Make": "Toyota",
  "model": "Corolla",
  "Color": "red",
  "Year": 1998
 },
 {
  "VIN": "wqeiryu",
  "Make": "Honda",
  "model": "Civic",
  "Color": "white",
  "Year": 1997
 }
]

sql = "INSERT INTO carsTEST (VIN, Make, Year, Color, username) VALUES"

for jo in json_data:
    new_vin = jo['VIN']
    new_make = jo['Make']
    new_year = jo['Year']
    new_color = jo['Color']
    value_sql = "('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}'),".format(new_vin, new_make, new_year, new_color)
    sql = sql + value_sql

sql = sql.rstrip(',') + ";"

print(sql)
```

Edit1:
The method should be something like :

```
@app.route('/api/addcar', methods=['POST'])
def adding_stuff():
    request_data = request.get_json() # post body must be a json array
    sql = "INSERT INTO carsTEST (VIN, Make, Year, Color) VALUES"
    for jo in request_data:
        new_vin = jo['VIN']
        new_make = jo['Make']
        new_year = jo['Year']
        new_color = jo['Color']
        value_sql = "('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}'),".format(new_vin, new_make, new_year, new_color)
        sql = sql + value_sql
    sql = sql.rstrip(',') + ";"
    conn = create_connection()
    execute_query(conn, sql)  # This will execute the query
    return 'Post worked'
```

Comment: But how can I do it to where I am just coding the backend and I am waiting for the user to input the json_data variable?

Comment: @Rhythm The definition of "json_data" can be replaced with request_data = request.get_json() and you can build a raw sql that can be executed out of the json data the user offers.